# Matlabpool causes some problems with surf() function

Tags: matlab, save-as, parfor

I encountered a problem using parfor in Matlab. I run code below inside a function called within a parfor loop:

- If I open matlabpool, program crash on `saveas` function;
- If I do not open matlabpool, everything works well;
- If I comment both `surf` calls, again everything works well, even with matlabpool open.

I normally **saveas** with .pdf format but if I **saveas** with .fig format everything works well. .fig format is the only format that does not cause problems. 
Of course, I cannot debug parallel loop because parfor with matlabpool open does not allow to step into, therefore without matlabpool open I can see that every variable is good.

Am I missing something? I cannot find any known problem using surf within parfor loop. There are too many strange issues to try to understand where is the true problem, so I ask if someone has had a similar problem.

```
threads=4;

matlabpool(threads);

parfor i=1:threads
    t=getCurrentTask();
    tmpPath=['tmp' num2str(t.ID)];
    importaData = open([tmpPath '\' 'Title','.mat']);
    if isempty(importaData) == 0
        f8 = importaData.data; %clear importaData;

        hf8 = figure('Name','Title','NumberTitle','off', 'Color',[1 1 1], 'visible', 'off');

        hold on; grid on; subplot(f8.subplot1);
        title('Title');
        h = surf(f8.x1,f8.y1,f8.surfVal1); set(h, 'EdgeAlpha', 0.05); axis('square'); view(0,90);
        xlabel(f8.xLabel1); ylabel(f8.yLabel1); zlabel(f8.zLabel1);
        hold on; subplot(f8.subplot2);
        h = surf(f8.x2,f8.y2,f8.surfVal2); set(h, 'EdgeAlpha', 0.05); axis('square'); view(0,90);
        xlabel(f8.xLabel2); ylabel(f8.yLabel2); zlabel(f8.zLabel2);

        cd(tmpPath);
        saveas(hf8, 'Title', 'pdf'); close(hf8);
        cd('..');
        delete([tmpPath '\' 'Title','.mat']);
    else
        error = -1;        
    end;
end;
```

UP: Ok, this is a finished program that lead the error:

> Error using distcomp.remoteparfor/getCompleteIntervals (line 22) The
>   session that parfor is using has shut down.

My goal is to save `Title.mat` into a pdf file. Of course Title.mat contains consistent and correct data. Every Thread should go into an exclusive directory that contains a .mat file to `translate`. If I DO NOT open pool, everything works as expected. If I save in .fig format, everything works as expected.

Comment: No, sorry, I forget it, I run Windows 7 64 bit...

Comment: Considering [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/programming-considerations.html), it seems that you are doing several things in the parfor loop which are potentially not thread-safe or at least just not well suited for parallelization. E.g. `clear` in the workspace, figure handles or file-accesses.
In order to help, it would be good to have the full code (including the subfunctions and the loop itself) of a minimal but complete sample that gives you an error, including the exact error message.

Comment: I update first post. The code is the same as before, I only changed files name. Removing every "clear" calls do not resolve problem. Do not acces files is of course out of question. And, again, why this problem come out only whe I use surf to save data? This is a lot tricky...

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. So you are using Normal (local) and not distributed mode, right? Is Line 22 referring to the `cd` command? If so can you try the program without changing directories for a test? Also, I think that there are some parfor-specific log files created by Matlab somewhere, not sure if its in `tempdir`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I'm using Local. Yes, it is `cd` command. Without using `cd` it still give error. I cannot find anything that could be a matlab log file.

Comment: If you remove `cd` (I assume both of them), on what line is the error? Also, I've read that moving the processing (everything between `parfor` and `end`) to a function may change the behavior. If there's no log-file, you could add some debug-prints of your own to localize the error better and see in which order the different threads are processing stuff.

Comment: If I remove `cd` the error line is the same, on `saveas` line. Moving all instruction to a function do not help. The threads order is of course random and the first thread that arrive on `saveas` line, leads the problem. The specific function that crash is `hardcopy` that is called inside `saveas(line 154) -> print(line 283) -> render(line 142)`. `hardcopy.m` do not contain any code, so I have reach a dead point in my investigation.